# Android: Guarantee sending of data to a server

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have code to post data to a server, but sometimes, if the network is slow, the data does not get through. My app is somewhat similar to a messenger program, and I want to post and store every message in a MySQL database. My client-side code is shown below:

```
  try{ 

                     // URLEncode user defined data

                       String loginValue    = URLEncoder.encode(login.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
                       String fnameValue  = URLEncoder.encode(fname.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
                       String emailValue   = URLEncoder.encode(email.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
                       String passValue    = URLEncoder.encode(pass.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");

                    // Create http cliient object to send request to server

                       HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();

                    // Create URL string

                     String URL = "http://****/httpget.php?user="+loginValue+"&name="+fnameValue+"&email="+emailValue+"&pass="+passValue;

                    //Log.i("httpget", URL);

                   try
                    {
                                  String SetServerString = "";

                                // Create Request to server and get response

                                  HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
                                 ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                                 SetServerString = Client.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

                                  // Show response on activity 

                                 content.setText(SetServerString);
                     }
                   catch(Exception ex)
                      {
                             content.setText("Fail!");
                       }
                }
              catch(UnsupportedEncodingException ex)
               {
                       content.setText("Fail");
                }
```

... and here is my server-side PHP code:

```
<?php

         $name  = urldecode($_POST['name']);
         $user     = urldecode($_POST['user']);
         $email   = urldecode($_POST['email']);
         $pass    = urldecode($_POST['pass']);

        print " ==== GET REQUEST DATA =====
                 Name: $name 
                 Email: $email
                 User: $user 
                 Pass: $pass";

?>
```

Comment: in above code it seems that ur code tries to send data only once hence there need to retrial mechanism present

Comment: Should you really be sending password via GET? Surely it would be safer to use POST.

Comment: @GoBusto  ya i know it just for demo purpose

Comment: @diva retrial mechanism present whats that can you give me more info on that

Comment: Use POST method for send user information.

Comment: Do you obtained some exceptions in your application? If yes, you can send message to queue(ArrayList for example), and resend it to server later, when there will be good connection.

Comment: Should i use websocket to connect android with my php server is it possible

Comment: i just ment to say that u need keep check of internet if incase no available u need save that in queue or somthing where in u can push back on network